Cancel previous laravel livewire requests on debounced inputs
I need some help cancelling previous long-running Laravel Livewire requests in my Laravel 11 project. Essentially, my database has millions of rows and I have a debounced input in my livewire component, when typing, despite there being 100ms delay, if a request is pending for many seconds, a new request is also stacked up causing additional load on the database as two requests are now pending causing excess query usage.
How can I cancel the previous stacked up requests before it so that only the newest runs:
Here's my input:
<x-text-input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="block w-full md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4" placeholder="Search" wire:model.live.debounce.100ms="search" data-lpignore="true" />

And my component:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Pages\Applications;

use Livewire\Attributes\Url;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Application;

class ApplicationIndex extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    #[Url]
    public string $search = '';
    public string $sortField = 'created_at';
    public string $sortDirection = 'desc';
    public bool $showAdvancedFilters = false;
    public array $filters = [
        'product' => null
    ];

    public function sortBy(string $field)
    {
        $this->sortDirection = $this->sortField === $field
            ? $this->sortDirection = $this->sortDirection == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
            : 'asc';

        $this->sortField = $field;
    }

    public function updatedSearch()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function updatedFilters()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->authorize('viewAny', Application::class);

        sleep(3); // <-- here lies the problem?? 

        $applications = Application::withCount('entries')->with([
            'entry'
        ])->when($this->filters['product'], fn ($query, $product) => $query->where('product_type', $product))
            ->searchExact(['id', 'hash', 'email', 'mobile', 'birthday', 'postcode'], $this->search)
            ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortDirection)
            ->simplePaginate(10);

        return view('livewire.pages.applications.application-index', [
            'applications' => $applications
        ]);
    }
}

